# Nonlinear approximation by piecewise constants and the expectation of the error

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, probability-distributions, numerical-methods, approximation

Suppose $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $f$ is continuous, monotonic, and of bounded variation on $\Omega$ with $M:= \text{Var}_\Omega(f).$

Let $\| \cdot\|:=\| \cdot\|_{L_\infty(\Omega)}.$ Let $T=\{0=t_0,...,t_n=1\}$ be the uniform partition of the range of $f,a_k$ is the average of the function values at the endpoints on $[f^{-1}(t_{k-1}),f^{-1}(t_k)],$  and $S_n(x):=a_k,x\in[f^{-1}(t_{k-1}),f^{-1}(t_k)),k=1,...,n.$ Then there is a theorem says that$$\|f-S_n\|\le M/2n.$$

---

The above theorem uses the uniform partition of the range. Now if we use a random partition of the range of $f$ and assume the partition points $t_i \sim U(0,1), $ where $i=1,..,n-1.$ Can we get the result $E(\| f-S_n\|)\le C/n$ for some constant $C$? How to prove or disprove it? I have trouble expressing the expectation explicitly.

I showed that the expectation of the length of each subinterval is $1/n.$ But I am not sure if the result is useful.

Comment: I don't entirely understand how $S_n$ is constructed when $f$ isn't injective. Is it that wherever $t_{k-1}<f(x)<t_k$, $S_n(x)=\frac{t_{k-1}+t_k}{2}$? Or do you take the median operation in the domain instead, so that the partition of the range induces a partition of the domain and then you approximate $f$ on that partition of the domain using the midpoint rule?

Comment: (Also, I guess the domain and range of $f$ are both $[0,1]$? This isn't clear from what you wrote.)

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much. I already changed the problem. $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: OK. So is "the median value" $f$ at the median, or the average of the function values at the endpoints? It seems like it must be the latter because the former would not give your result (consider $n=1$ and $f(x)=x^N$ for some large $N$).

Comment: @Ian. Yes, thank you very much for your suggestion. Also, I changed the statement that I want to prove.

Comment: OK, well now you can just explicitly calculate that $\| f - S_n \|_{L^\infty}$ is just the maximum of the $|t_k-t_{k-1}|/2$ regardless of what they are exactly. This maximum will be just half the maximum length of subintervals of the partition. You can fix some constant $C$ such that with large probability this is less than $C/n$ but there is no $C$ that is guaranteed to work with probability 1.

Comment: @Ian.  I did not know how to solve the expectation of $max(t_k-t_{k-1}).$ But I've proved that the expectation of the length of each interval is $1/n.$ So, I did not understand there is no such a $C$ intuitively. Can you give more details? Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not talking about in expectation. I'm saying that there's no universal $C$ that works for all $n$ and all $t_k$. This is just because it's possible, but unlikely, for the $t_k$ to be clumped near the endpoints, in which case the "middle" subinterval that bridges the gap is large, which causes a large error.